# how install version 0.20 or 0.40 react-native

Tags: react-native

everybody.

I want to test the new version 0.20 of react-native, but NPM has the version 0.19.
¿How i can install the new version 0.20 or 0.40 in MAC?

thanks

ref:
in GitHub Show the versions 0.20 and 0.40

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes a while to get the versions pushed to npm.. 0.20 is the newest version. There is no 0.40 (don't confuse it with 0.4.0). Installing should install the latest release. I'm not sure how familiar you are with NPM but addiing @versionNumber to the end of a package will install that version. e.g. npm install react-native@0.20